# Discrete Mathematics question regarding Propostional Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

This is a discrete mathematics question. Specifically Propositonal Logic. I have not been able to solve this using Logical laws (boolean laws). If someone could please help me solve this using ONLY boolean laws, I would appreciate it. I am finding it hard to solve the questions involving three variables. Is there a trick to it?

Proof that this is a tautology.

$((p\land \lnot q) \leftrightarrow r) \to(r \to p)$

Also is it at all possible to solve this using inference rules?

Comment: I think you are asking how to rewrite the expression as an "obvious" tautology using "Boolean laws".  Isn't it straightforward to rewrite the logical operations in terms of (say) conjunction and negation?  Give it a try...

Comment: You show it is a topology by making a truth table.